# Enabling Windows Features through Python won't let DISM have elevated access even after letting Python get elevated access through functions

Tags: python, windows, cmd, uac, dism

I'm trying to enable Windows Features through Python through functions. Here's the scripts that I've used:

UAC.py:

```py
def gainadminaccess():
    import os
    import sys
    import win32com.shell.shell as shell
    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

    if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gainadminaccess()
```

winfeatures.py

```py
def install(feature):
    packageName = feature
    import os
    os.system("cmd /k dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:" + packageName + "/All")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    install()
```

enablefeatures.py:

```py
import UAC
import winfeatures
import os

UAC.gainadminaccess()
winfeatures.install('VirtualMachinePlatform')
```

I'm OK with passing the UAC prompt, but when arriving at the feature part through winfeatures, it will show:

```
Error: 740

Elevated permissions are required to run DISM. 
Use an elevated command prompt to complete these tasks.
```

which I assume that DISM didn't get elevated access. Any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
UAC.gainadminaccess()
winfeatures.install('VirtualMachinePlatform')
```

The first line will launch a new process.  The second line executes but it is still running as non-admin:

I think you want this instead:

```
def gainadminaccess():
    import os
    import sys
    import win32com.shell.shell as shell
    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

    isAdmin = sys.argv[-1] == ASADMIN

    if not isAdmin:
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    
    return isAdmin # returns true if this script is already running as admin
```

Then in your other file:

```
if UAC.gainadminaccess():
    winfeatures.install('VirtualMachinePlatform')
```